# iOS enterprise app - long term background task with AsiHTTPRequest

Tags: ios, background, download, asihttprequest, task

I'm dealing with a long period download (2 hours). The app won't be distributed into the apple app store. So that restrictions don't matter.

My Question is following. I have an ASIHttpRequest bulk processor realized with the operation queue. Now, in foreground everything works fine and also it will be continued in background for the 600 seconds period.

I think the best would be a "hack" to increase or reset the backgroundTimeRemaining time.
But do I have other options there, to extend the download period to the 2 or more hours?

Cheers Christian

Comment: I'm not sure iOS devices should be handling data sets that take 2 hours to download.  Seems like a heavy load for a phone or tablet.  The battery could run out before the download is complete.

Comment: that is clear, but it doesn't matter. The most important thing is to download that data.

Answer (score 1):

if you play a silent wav in the background then your app will not get killed by the watch dog.

Comment: Only if the background mode is set to audio and the AV session is set to true.

Comment: ok but then the play icon will be shown in the status bar, right? Do I have to play a long silent wav file, or would it also be possible to repeat or short file?

Comment: ok that solutions worked for me. I recorded a silent wav file that is being played in background as long as the download is active.